# How to check if the value in a <td> is null and show a text based on that in another <td>?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Im making an interface for a page where it shows employees in and out times from a database. I need to show a column to show whether the employee attended work for that day or not. (It shows "Yes" if the in and out times are not null) I tried the code below but couldnt get it to work

```js
var temp = document.getElementsByClassName("table-custom-temp");
var list = document.getElementsByName("attendance");

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

  if (!temp) {
    document.getElementsByName("attendance")[i].innerHTML = "No";
  } else {
    document.getElementsByName("attendance")[i].innerHTML = "Yes"
  }
}
```

```css
.table-custom {
  padding: 12px 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
}

.table-custom-temp {
  padding: 12px 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table style="margin-left: 20px">
  <tr>
    <th class="table-custom">Employee Name</th>
    <th class="table-custom">Attended Today</th>
    <th class="table-custom">In Time</th>
    <th class="table-custom">Out Time</th>

  </tr>

  <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">

    <tr>
      <td class="table-custom">
        <c:out value="${row.name}" />
      </td>
      <td name="attendance" class="table-custom"></td>
      <td class="table-custom-temp">
        <c:out value="${row.in}" />
      </td>
      <td class="table-custom-temp">
        <c:out value="${row.out}" />
      </td>
      <td class="table-custom"></td>

      <td class="table-custom"></td>
      <td class="table-custom"></td>
    </tr>

  </c:forEach>

</table>
```

The items come from the database perfectly. but the Attended Today column always show "Yes" even when the in and out times are null. Im pretty sure the problem is when I used `getElementsByClassName` but I cant figure out what the problem is. Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Your check `if (!temp) { ` will always be false. That's the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a correct if condition to show yes no label. You would need a way to target the in time and out time values using selector. For this, you can add the two new classes (say in-time and out-time) to these tds.

```
<td class="table-custom-temp in-time">
   <c:out value="${row.in}" />
</td>
<td class="table-custom-temp out-time">
   <c:out value="${row.out}" />
</td>
```

And then get these values in if condition to see if there are not empty.

```
  var temp = document.getElementsByClassName("table-custom-temp");
  var list = document.getElementsByName("attendance");
  var listInTime = document.getElementsByClassName("in-time");
  var listOutTime = document.getElementsByClassName("out-time");

  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (listInTime[i].innerText.trim() == "" && listOutTime[i].innerText.trim() == "") {
       list[i].innerHTML = "No";
    } else {
       list[i].innerHTML = "Yes"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can't believe I completely missed out that I can get the in and out time like that.

Comment: Glad it helps :)